# CSS selector logic

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I do not understand what _MD, _S or _T is doing in this css. I want to understand what\why it's formatting. I also want to fix the formatting so all three bars look like the first image.

If I use [#trackBar_MD] to apply the css to the first Trackbar it works fine.
This top bar is what I want them all to look like. 
[image]
If I remove the _MD, _S and _T. it does not format it properly.
[image]
If I use the below code using [.trackbar] and the _MD,_S,_T
It formats all the trackbars like the [#trackBar]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ9Tu.png)

The below code generated the 3rd image.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VerticalSlider.aspx.cs" Inherits="SliderTool.VerticalSlider" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">
        .dxeTBHSys.center 
        {
            margin: 60px auto;
        }
        .dxeTBVSys.center 
        {
            margin: auto;
        }

        .trackBar_MD
        {
            background: transparent url("/Content/img/Drag.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
            left: 174px; 
            top: -7px;
            width: 50px; 
            height: 16px;
            background-size: 100%;
        }

        .trackBar_T
        {
            background-image:none;
            background-color:black;
        }
        
        .trackBar_S
        {
            background-image:none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div style="float: left; width: 100%">
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 350px">
            <div style="border: thin solid black;  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 350px">
                <br /><br />
            <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="trackBar" CssClass="center trackBar trackBar_MD trackBar_S trackBar_T" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="50" Step="1" 
                LargeTickInterval="10" SmallTickFrequency="5" EnableViewState="false">
            </dx:ASPxTrackBar>
                            <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="trackBar1" CssClass="center trackBar trackBar_MD trackBar_S trackBar_T" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="50" Step="1" 
                LargeTickInterval="10" SmallTickFrequency="5" EnableViewState="false">
            </dx:ASPxTrackBar>
                            <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="trackBar2" CssClass="center trackBar trackBar_MD trackBar_S trackBar_T" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="50" Step="1" 
                LargeTickInterval="10" SmallTickFrequency="5" EnableViewState="false">
            </dx:ASPxTrackBar>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Rendered Page
http://pastebin.com/XPvF0ZSJ

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML so we can quickly debug the CSS.

Comment: Added Pastebin for rendered page.